# PHP salt and hash password not matching

Tags: php, hash, salt

I've created a page that generates a 40-character salt, then takes the inputted password and creates a hash using this PHP code and inserts the salt and hashed password into the database using (this is just the relevant line):

```
$hashedpassword = sha1($password . $salt);
```

Then in the login process, I use the inputted password and retrieve the salt from the db to create the has using the same line of code (again, this is just the relevant line):

```
$hashedpassword = sha1($storedPassword . $storedSalt);
```

But it doesn't match the hashed password stored, so to see if there was an error, I "echoed" the information so I could read what was happening:

```
$storedSalt = $row_rsSaltLookup['salt'];
$storedPassword = $row_rsSaltLookup['password'];
$storedHashedPassword = $row_rsSaltLookup['hashedpassword'];
    //use the stored salt to hash the user's submitted password
$hashedpassword = sha1($storedPassword . $storedSalt);
echo "Salt: " . $storedSalt . "<br/>";
echo "Stored Password: " . $storedPassword . "<br/>";
echo "Stored Hashed Password: " . $storedHashedPassword . "<br/>";
echo "Pre-hash: " . $storedPassword . $storedSalt . "<br/>";
echo "Hashed Password: " . $hashedpassword . "<br/>";
echo "re-Hashed Password: " . sha1($storedPassword . $storedSalt) . "<br/>";
echo "re-Hashed Password 2: " . sha1($storedPassword . $storedSalt) . "<br/>";
if($storedHashedPassword != $hashedpassword) {
     echo "NO MATCH";
}else{
     echo "MATCH";
}
exit();
```

And I get this as a result:

```
Salt: 4039505cc4efae2
Stored Password: ujwiervdhyf
Stored Hashed Password: aa27c197dfd88cd2f0d46b84d259016a15bd3954
Pre-hash: ujwiervdhyf4039505cc4efae2
Hashed Password: b06193ed26617c449902ac813376cf0c33bec3d1
re-Hashed Password: b06193ed26617c449902ac813376cf0c33bec3d1
re-Hashed Password 2: b06193ed26617c449902ac813376cf0c33bec3d1
NO MATCH
```

In this example, the "salt" is generated and put together with the password (Stored Password) from when the account is created and hashed (Stored Hashed Password).
When I go to login, I get the salt from the db and add it to the password on the login, then hash that and compare it to the stored hashed password, which should be the same?
So I'm wondering where I went wrong because I can't seem to figure out why the hashes don't match.

Comment: Maybe [you should use bcrypt for storing password](http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/)

Comment: So you're storing the plaintext password **and** a hash of the same password?  Your thought process here is hard to follow.

Comment: Err, which hash did you store? You missed that to put into the debug-output, too. Take care that MySQL truncates data silently in case the column-size is too small.

Comment: I was going to delete the field for the plaintext password once I knew I had it working. I should have said that this was my first time doing it, so I wanted to be able to follow the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
$hashedpassword = sha1($storedPassword . $storedSalt);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is the hash you stored when the account was first created, then you're doing this wrong. You're hashing a hash, which will not work. It should be

```
$hash_of_attempted_password = sha1($password_from_login_form . $storedSalt);
if ($hash_of_attemped_password == $hash_of_original_password) {
   ... it's a match ...
}
```

Comment: The first hash is created with the password from the form and the generated salt value. That salt and the original password, plus the hashed password are stored (the plain text field will be removed later). I'm comparing the password on the login page + the stored salt and hashing that to compare it to the stored hash. That's what I've been reading in the tutorials. I'll just check my logic to make sure that's what I'm doing.